# Auto hide status bar

Tags: android

**Is there a way to auto hide the status bar?**

I've already made the status bar hidden when activity starts and I thought it will automatically disappear after a few seconds or when the user interacts whith something else but it doesn't. And I'm still unable to make it disappear.

Here's my code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution after reading this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY // hide status bar and nav bar after a short delay, or if the user interacts with the middle of the screen
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using these flags:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Google has a great write up on it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: I tried your code but it changed nothing since what I actually want is a way to get the status bar automatically disappear after a few seconds when it shows or when the user clicks elsewhere. However I checked your [link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) and found the solution with [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY). Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, glad the link helped

Answer (score 0):

Our base activity has a method to make it full screen.
Call this in `onCreate` after `super.onCreate` and before `setContentView()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    removeTitleBar();
    setContentView(your_layout);
}
```

this is the method:

```
    protected void removeTitleBar() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //Remove notification bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

This works for any api level as far as we support it. But we do not go as low as api 8 or so.
Sometimes 15, mostly 17+.
Hope this helps.